# Apply MediatR requests dynamically to objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatr

I am trying to use MediatR in my web api application. My requirements states that, when a request arrive, it should be executed against a variable number of instances.
For example, suppose I have a `CreateRequest` command and that this command, depending on the input of the request, should be executed against two objects `AType` and `BType`. By creating a simple handler, as in the following sample

```
internal class CreateRequestHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<CreateRequest, CreateResponse> 
{
    public async Task<CreateResponse> Handle( CreateRequest message ) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

it would be an handler responsibility to determine on which objects apply the command?

**EDIT**

As per @Aaron request here is a sample on what I am trying to achieve. Suppose I have an api which enable/disable components. Actually there are many components available and the api should be able to disable a single component or a set of them depending on the input received.

`TRequest` and `TResponse` are equals for every handler because all components implement the same interface.

For this reason I have a set of command/handler each of them disabling a single component. However I would like to avoid that every handler get materialized and run. Instead, I only would like mediator to send the request to those components that are identified in the request input.

Comment: As in you want multiple handlers to handle a single request?

Comment: Right. But I would like to wrap all handler responses in a single upper level response. Also I would like to dynamically decide which types would receive the command at runtime.

Comment: You can get the single upper level response using the PipelineBehaviors.  As for having a single request be handled by multiple handlers you might need to look at the notifications.  Unless you're saying each request is handled by a single handler but you want to decide which handler at runtime.

Comment: Right for the first suggestion, I was expecting that it would be the way. However notifications does not work as you can not return any type from a notification handler. You've got the point: I would like to decide which handler enable at runtime

Comment: MediatR already should be deciding which handler at runtime. Can you give an example of what the requests might look like so I can better understand?

Comment: Sure! Have a look at my edit. Hope that can clarify a bit the question